# Reduce array of emoji objects to get count of each emoji javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, emoji

I have a javascript array as follows:

```json
[
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
    {moodSymbol: ""},
]
```

How can I get the count of each emoji and still keep the moodSymbol key name as such:

```json
const data = [
{
    moodSymbol: "",
    count: 3
},
{
    moodSymbol: "",
    count: 2
}, 
...
]
```

I also want the **top 5** with the highest count. I tried using reduce and I honestly have been having so much trouble getting this to work with emojis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object (hash map) to count each symbol and then generate the results array.

To get the top 5, just sort the result in decending order and then splice the array to have only 5 elements.

```js
let arr = [ {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}, {moodSymbol: ""}];

let obj = {};

arr.forEach(e => {
    obj[e.moodSymbol] = obj[e.moodSymbol] || 0;
    obj[e.moodSymbol]++;
});

let res = Object.entries(obj).map(e => ({moodSymbol: e[0], count: e[1]}));

res.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count).splice(5);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = Array.from(data.reduce((acc,{ moodSymbol: emoji }) => {
  const count = acc.get(emoji) || 0
  acc.set(emoji, count + 1)
  return acc
}, new Map()).entries()).map(([moodSymbol, count]) => ({ moodSymbol, count }))
```

If you want top 5 you can just sort by `count` then slice off 5.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const symbols = [
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" },
  { moodSymbol: "" }
];

const result = symbols.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const oldCountIndex = acc.findIndex(
    (old) => old.moodSymbol === curr.moodSymbol
  );

  if (oldCountIndex > -1) {
    acc[oldCountIndex].count++;
  } else {
    acc.push({ moodSymbol: curr.moodSymbol, count: 1 });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the method using `Array.reduce`, along with `Object.values`, `Array.sort` and then finally `Array.slice`.

- `Object.values`, In order to convert the final result returned by `Array.reduce` into an array of values. Each object consists of `moodSymbol` and `count` properties
- `Array.sort` in order to sort the array in descending order
- `Array.slice` in order to get the top 5 items from the final sorted array.

```js
let data = [{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""},{moodSymbol:""}];

const getTop5 = (data) => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {moodSymbol}) => {
    res[moodSymbol] = {
      moodSymbol,
//Incrementing the count by 1, when matched `moodSymbol` found in the result object.
      count: (res[moodSymbol]?.count || 0) + 1
    };
    return res;
  }, {})
  return Object.values(finalRes).sort((a1, a2) => a2.count-a1.count).slice(0, 5);
}

console.log(getTop5(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reducing the array down to an object with emojis as keys and counts as values. Then you can map the entries of that object back to an array.

```js
const counts = Object.entries(
 // reduce the array to an object. if you find an existing entry of your emoji, 
 // add one unit to value (count). otherwise, add a new entry with a value of 1
 symbols.reduce((a, { moodSymbol: s }) => ((a[s] = (a[s] || 0) + 1), a), {})
// get the entries of that object and map it back into an array of objects,
// with the key (emoji) as the `moodSymbol`, and the value (count) as the `count`
).map((e) => ({ moodSymbol: e[0], count: e[1] }));
```

To get the top five, you should sort the array by the `count` property, then slice off everything but the top five.

```js
const symbols = [
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" },
{ moodSymbol: "" }
];

const counts = Object.entries(
 symbols.reduce((a, { moodSymbol: s }) => ((a[s] = (a[s] || 0) + 1), a), {})
).map((e) => ({ moodSymbol: e[0], count: e[1] }));

const topFive = counts.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count).slice(0, 5);

console.log(counts);
console.log(topFive);
```